# matlab arrayfun on gpu with class methods

Tags: matlab, oop, gpu, matlab-gpu

Consider the following simple class

```
classdef A < handle

    properties
        M;
    end


    methods
        function obj= A(m)
               obj.M=m;
        end

        function foo(obj)
            Array = linspace(0,obj.M,100);
            arrayfun(@obj.bar,Array);
        end

         function foo2(obj)
            Array = gpuArray.linspace(0,obj.M,100);
            arrayfun(@obj.bar,Array);
         end

        function y = bar(obj,x)
            y = x^2/obj.M;
        end
    end

end
```

Now a run

> `>>` a=A(1);
>
> `>>` a.foo();
>
> `>>` a.foo2();
>
> Error using gpuArray/arrayfun Function passed as first input argument contains
>   unsupported 'MCOS' language feature  'CLASSDEF'. For more information
>   see Tips and Restrictions.
>
> Error in A/foo2 (line 20)
>                arrayfun(@obj.bar,Array);

Notice that `foo()` and `foo2()` are the same function with the only exception, `foo2()` is supposed to run the GPU version of `arrayfun`.

Is there any workaround or trick to make `foo2()` above working, i.e. class method run on GPU? Consider `bar()` cannot be static or so as it supposed to use class properties.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `classdef` objects in code running on the GPU. You will have to create a function that takes each one of the class properties it uses as an input argument. Something like this *should* work (not tested!):

```matlab
classdef A < handle

    properties
        M;
    end

    methods
        function obj = A(m)
            obj.M = m;
        end

        function foo2(obj)
            Array = gpuArray.linspace(0,obj.M,100);
            arrayfun(@(x)bar(obj.M,x),Array);
        end
    end

end

function y = bar(M,x)
    y = x^2/M;
end
```

If your function `bar` could return as outputs any new values for object properties, which your function `foo2` would write to those properties.

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky: But there is no `classdef` involved in that call! Did you clear your previous definition of the class? (`clear classes`).